# How to check my targeted file's extention from the public directory according to file name?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an employee folder in the public directory. A picture can be uploaded there with different extensions. The extension can be either small or capital letters.

example :
A user can upload a file such as listed below:

```
 12345.JPG Or 12345.jpg Or 12345.PNG Or 12345.png
```

When I am going to show/view this uploaded image file according to an employee number, first I need to know the uploaded file's correct extension from the public directory.

I have tried to show using below one only for one extension but not for all.

```
<img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle"
    src="{{ (file_exists(public_path('/hrm/employee/'.$employee->employee_no.'.JPG'))) ? asset('/hrm/employee/'.$employee->employee_no.'.JPG') : asset('/hrm/employee/'.$employee->employee_no.'.jpg') }}"
    alt="User profile picture">
```

Can someone please tell me how can I show the image name from the directory without knowing the uploaded file's extension for a specific employee number?

Comment: Try this : Input::file('thumb')->getClientOriginalExtension();

Comment: @Chandni Soni  sorry I want to retrieve the image name from public directory ( which already uploaded) not from input:file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file extension using pathinfo() method as shown below,

```
$filename = "12345";

$files = glob("F:\FilePath\\$filename.*");

if (count($files) > 0)
foreach ($files as $file)
 {
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    echo $filename.".".$info["extension"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $directory = 'your folder path';
 $files = File::allFiles($directory);
 foreach ($files as $file) {
    $name= explode('/', $file);
    $full_file_name = end($name);
    $ext= explode('.', $full_file_name)[1];
}
```